# How to get value of key in JSON object

Tags: java, json

I have a json file which will update every so often and an example of it is this;

```
{
"Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Intraday (60min) prices and volumes",
    "2. Symbol": "ASX:NAB",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2017-08-28 02:00:00",
    "4. Interval": "60min",
    "5. Output Size": "Compact",
    "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Time Series (60min)": {
    "2017-08-28 02:00:00": {
        "1. open": "30.3600",
        "2. high": "30.4400",
        "3. low": "30.3600",
        "4. close": "30.4000",
        "5. volume": "348096"
    },
    "2017-08-28 01:00:00": {
        "1. open": "30.3800",
        "2. high": "30.4100",
        "3. low": "30.3500",
        "4. close": "30.3500",
        "5. volume": "251213"
       }
 }
```

I was wondering instead of calling

```
  JSONObject example= (JSONObject) example2.get("2017-08-28 02:00:00")
```

every time i want the data from the object, is there a way of doing this in a loop? Dynamically changing the value of the .get?

I know how retrieve the data from the objects, i just dont know how to get the call the object without directly putting its name into the .get. The reason why it is a problem is because there will be hundreads of objects which have the format of "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"

EDIT:
I have added in the FOLLOWING code

```
 Iterator<String> keys = example2.keys();
```

However eclipse is saying that is is an undefined method for a JSONObject

Answer (score 0):

You can get the keys, and loop thrugh them, like this:

```
Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
String key = keys.next(); 
String value = json.optString(key);
```

Comment: When i do this it has a red line under it? i dont know how to fix it - http://i.imgur.com/rPID4DB.png

Comment: `example2.keys()` doesn't work? what is example2 ?

Comment: @peter    Can you post your code here?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/C5K5ZjCU - it says keys is not a defined method for for the type JSONObject @UrvashiSoni

Comment: `jsonObject.getSet()` will give you the set of keys in your JSON, through which you can iterate using for each loop.


`for (Object key : obj.keySet()) { 
 String kryStr = (String) key;
 Object keyValue = obj.get(kryStr);
 System.out.println(kryStr + " : " + keyValue);
}`